# How can I programatically click the facebook 'Post' button inside a webbrowser control

Tags: c#, facebook, webbrowser-control, sendkeys

I have a webbrowser control that loads facebook, uses SendKeys to write a message, but I cannot find a way to 'click' the Post button.

I have tried stuff like this:

```
HtmlElement button = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("_42ft");
button.InvokeMember("Click");
```

When I used 'inspect elements' in a regular webbrowers, the following html code seems to be the Post button.

```
<button class="_42ft _4jy0 _11b _4jy3 _4jy1 selected _51sy" type="submit" value="1" data-ft='{"tn":"+{"}'>Post</button>
```

I've tried all of these 5 character strings thinking the are the button name, but they are all null when I attempt to click them with `button.InvokeMember("Click");`

This is driving me nuts.   Yeah, I know I could use the facebook API, but I find it confusing, and their last update broke my program.

Comment: try it with `u_0_l`, as i see this value in chrome...

Comment: I'm far from an expert in web development, but by first glance it looks to me like you may have `Id` and `class` mixed up. If I recall correctly, you should extract a collection through `HtmlElementCollection coll = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByClassName("_42ft _4jy0 _11b _4jy3 selected _51sy` & then iterate through that collection to find the correct button. -- Again, I don't know much about this so I might be completely mistaken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use GetElementById you need to provide value of ID attribute of the element. The button element you have provided does not have an ID attribute set.

What you could do is get collection of all button elements:

```
var buttons = Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
```

and filter them for one with attribute "class" of value "_42ft _4jy0 _11b _4jy3 _4jy1 selected _51sy":

```
var postButton = buttons.SingleOrDefault(x => x.GetAttribute("class").Equals("_42ft _4jy0 _11b _4jy3 _4jy1 selected _51sy"));
```

**BUT! it is a terribly bad idea to go with this approach**, because once they change value of class attribute on this element you will get null and have to update your code. I strongly advise you to use their API.

Comment: I know it's not the greatest approach, but the API no longer lets you programatically post to a facebook group unless you are the admin of the group.